# Is there an R chunk option to reduce margin?

Tags: r, r-markdown, margin

Do you know any option to introduce into the 
 ```` ```{r echo=FALSE, message=FALSE, warning=FALSE, paged.print=FALSE, results='asis'} ```` part in order to make a table with just a left margin (of the page) of 1. It's not really cute to impose 1 to all the document (I'm on pdf output). Thanks

Comment: Which method do you use to create the table? `kable`?

Comment: Sorry for my late response, I use `stargazer`. I use `column.sep.width = "-15pt"` but there maybe exist another way to keep to right size and just apply the table moving these margin

Comment: Can you post the call to `stargazer`? You will have to modify the output produced manually.

Comment: Here is : `stargazer(lm,lm2,lm3,lm4, type = "latex", title = "OLS Regressions", header=F, column.sep.width = "-15pt")`